How can I play MechWarrior 2?
My dad told me a lot about that game when he was younger and how he loved it. How can I play it, even at it's age (Disk or Digital)? I have seen videos of it and I kind of want to give it a go, because it looks fun. I really don't care if there is hardly any texture, just as long as it's playable.

Welcome to the site Alex! I've tweaked your question  a little bit to just focus on how you can play MechWarrior 2 in the modern day in order to make it more answerable. I hope you're able to figure out how to get the game working on modern systems. Cheers!

Oh thank you Wipqozn! I go off focus some times so I'm glad you helped me out there.

It's guys like you who make a guy feel welcome.

"My dad told me".... Wait a minute, people who played this game when they were young are dads now? [Checks calendar] Oh my.

Oops, I made people feel their age now. Lol, sorry. It's old, but a classic, and I like playing old games.

@RobertColumbia It's worse than that. My dad used to play this game as well. And I have kids. Sorry.

Under no circumstances should you google "emulator mechwarrior 2" and click the first link. That would be both unethical and wrong.

I remember when this game was released and it felt like the cutting edge of 3D graphics. Man, those were the days, when we were easily pleased ...

@RobertColumbia sigh... https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/409361/how-can-i-play-mechwarrior-2#comment573846_409369 I am also a dad... though my kids are not video-game age yet :P

MW2 came out the year my youngest kid was born. Both of my kids are now older than I was that year.

"Wow" - Owen Wilson.  That's neat.

PCGamingWiki gives quite a lot of detail on how you can play the PC version on modern systems. There are also many helpful videos on YouTube, which cover the differences between the multitude of different versions that were released.
From what I recall, many consider the original DOS (software-rendered) version to be the best. It doesn't have the textures that were added in the later 3D-accelerated versions (the surfaces are just shaded), but apparently it performs smoother and is more stable. I believe some of the accelerated versions were more buggy (this was right at the start - the initial 'wild west' phase of 3D API development). Otherwise, the Windows 95 and Titanium editions can be run using MechVM or DxWnd.
Sadly, I don't think the game ever saw a digital release (Battletech have apparently tried to bury it, in favor of their newer version). So, to play it legitimately, you would need to buy a physical CD off e.g. eBay. Be aware though that there are a lot of different versions flying around - many of the 3D-accelerated versions (S3 Virge, Matrox Mystique, etc) are not playable any more, since they used now-obsolete 3D graphics APIs. So, avoid those versions and stick to DOS, Pentium or Titanium.
Regarding the console versions - I believe they were quite different to the PC version. They were designed to be more 'arcadey', with simpler controls, since the controllers had relatively few buttons. The PC version was designed more like a flight simulator, where you have to use the whole keyboard to control the mech's various functions. So, the experience on console vs PC will probably be quite different.

"It doesn't have the textures that were added in the later 3D-accelerated versions"... The walk through I watched had that, so I wasn't expecting too much. Double thanks for the eBay warning too.

I played this game on my parents Windows 95 computer which was Pentium based - some 25ish years ago.  I have had success using MechVM to run this game though as well.

@TimmyJim I love it. So you can use MechVM on your computer now? If so, I'll mark this answer as correct.

@Alex it was some years ago (when I asked the first question for this tag), but it was on my Windows 10 PC and I was certainly playing the game without issue

@TimmyJim Oh, I see. Well I will have to check out how to use MechVM soon. I actually forgot about the computer voice. Oh man It talks way more then I do.

@Alex PCGamingWiki states that MechVM 'doesn't work on Windows 8 or later'. However, apparently DxWnd works up to Windows 11. The original DOS version of the game can be played in Dosbox and runs quite well, if I recall.

What about a MacOS? Will DxWnd or the other MW2 versions work on OS?

@Alex I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect probably not. Although they might work in Wine.

Makes sense. OS and Windows have their ups and downs, and gaming works better for Windows.

@Alex, the DOS version should, since Dosbox is pretty platform-independent.

Just for my knowledge, what does DOS stand for in this case. I'm thinking DOM, but that is HTML for web browsers.

@Alex MS DOS stands for Microsoft Disk Operating System. It was the (text terminal only) Microsoft O/S that preceded Windows 95. Prior to Win 95, Windows was juts a graphical application running on top of MS DOS.

@Alex Just a nitpick: OS is a general term that refers to any operating system, including windows. You're thinking of MacOS aka OSX, which is Apple's operating system.

Oh, yes. Thanks. I'm still learning all these terms for Hardware and Software. OSX and MacOS is Apple. I'll try to remember that.

The easiest way to play the game today would probably be to grab a copy of the 1997 PlayStation release from your preferred used console gaming dealer. This will play on an original PlayStation as well as on the PS2 or PS3. By going with a console version, you will avoid having to deal with configuring, tweaking, or troubleshooting your MS-DOS emulator.

Short, sweet, fun to eat, and easy as pie. Oh, but wasn't there a PC version too?

What is the point of playing a game, if you don't have to learn how your computer works ti get it running? Where would be the challenge and satisfaction?

Kids these days, will never learn the….joy…of making boot disks for game after game.

@suchiuomizu Today's tech makes it even harder to learn, in your words, "the joy of boot disks for game after game," because those things have become extincted from the tech world. I would love learning how to work with old tech.

@RobertColumbia I just realized, you answered at 0:00 UTC. That's funny.
